# Is it possible to make a variable that contains a reference of a function?

Tags: kotlin

for example:

```
fun aFunc() {
    print("hello")
}

fun main() {
    val test = aFunc //<-- this does not compile

    test()
}
```

Why is it not possible to make `test` equal to a reference of `aFunc` in this case, and is there a correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, you can either reference the function directly or create new function which calls the other one, both ways here:

```kotlin
val test = ::aFunc
val test2 = { aFunc() }
  
test()
test2()
```